# ASP.NET application not processing 404s beyond 2 levels deep

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

Can anyone explain to me why I would be able to trap and handle a 404 in code (in Application_Error) as long as the url does not contain more than 2 folder levels.

E.g. `www.mysite.com/bad/url` processes fine.

`www.mysite.com/really/bad/url`, on the other hand, seems to bypass the application altogether and gets handled separately by IIS.

*Edit*
As there's no response here, I've also posted on the IIS forums to see if I can get an answer:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1206916.aspx?ASP+NET+application+not+processing+404s+beyond+2+levels+deep

Comment: Is it (the subdirectory) set up as a virtual directory / application?  Or just a normal subdirectory?

Comment: It's neither... it doesn't exist. It's a random non-existent URL... For context, we're trying to redirect old URLs using a database.

Comment: Is there a file with extension specified in the request e.g. /really/bad/url/file.aspx or is it just the directory as you specified? e.g. /really/bad/url  -- different extensions can be handled differently.  I've never seen depth alone behave like this.

Comment: Does all request get handed off to asp.net by the IIS? Because then it might be an issue with the routing in your application itself.

Comment: @mikey - not convinced the extension should make a difference, we're using extension-less urls and Url Rewriting throughout our site with no problems. I've tested it fairly throughly, and it definitely appears to be a function of depth, not extension.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - is there a way I can test that?